# The function $\sqrt{z-a}\cdot \sqrt{z-a}$ has a branch in $C\setminus{[a,b]}$ for all $a,b\in \Bbb{C}$ using $z-a\over z-b$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the function $f(z)=\sqrt{z-a}\cdot \sqrt{z-a}$  has a branch in $C\setminus{[a,b]}$ for all $a,b\in \Bbb{C}$. **Hint:** $\phi={z-a\over z-b}$ maps $[a,b]$ to $\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$. I tried to use the hint and also found $\phi^{-1}$ so as to get close to a holomorphic composition to fit $f(z)$, but I am stuck here, and I can't quite see how I can form it. What should be the approahc here or the explanation for what makes a function that defines a continuous subset of $f(z)$ a branch...I could use some help here.

This question is referred to another question that is identical in result to this one. However, these are not identical in the attempt or in the solution, as they do not rely on the hint I am trying to utilize and connect to the given case, and in any case I do not quite understand the reference's comments and solutions, whose authors would not necessarily be as responsive to me as they might be to the referrence's OP.